# how to count number of objects created of inner class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, static, inner-classes

I have an activity and inside it I have a class called AsyncTask. Inside the AsyncTask class I want to declare a counter as a static variable but I can't because the AsyncTask class is assumed as an inner class to the mainActivity.

Is there any way to create a static variable inside the AsycTask "inner class" to count the number of objects created of the AsyncTask for an example?

**code**

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ....
    ....
    ....
    ....

    class MyAsync extends AsyncTask <void, Void, Void> {

        private static int counter = 0; // is not possible here
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a constructor to increment the `counter` inside the `AsyncTask`.

Do it like this :

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {
....
....
....
....
    int counter = 0; 
    class MyAsync extends AsyncTask <void, Void, Void> {

       MyAsync()
       {
           counter++;
       }
    }

}
```

> Logic behind this is : Constructor of any class will be called
>   everytime when the new object of that will created. Inside constructor
>   we have `counter++` so each time when the new object is created the
>   counter is incremented and You will have the count of number of
>   objects created.

Comment: ok but in this case, counter varibale should not be declared as static it could be nonstatic as well, isnt it?

Comment: @jankigadhiya : Are you gujrati ? :o

Answer (score 4):

You could just do something like this:

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static int counter = 0;

    // ...

    static class MyAsync extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void> {

        private MyAsync() {
            counter++;
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

This way `counter` will be incremented every time you create a new instance of `MyAsync`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a static inner class.

**code**

```
class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ....
    ....
    ....
    ....

    static class MyAsync extends AsyncTask <void, Void, Void> {

        private static int counter = 0; // is not possible here
    }

}
```